# How to upload a video using ACF in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am still at learning phase in WordPress. I cannot figure out in ACF which field type should I choose to upload a video file and which code should I write to show it at the front-end. Please look into the below code. I am using the_field('') but it isn't working. Can anyone help

```
                <video width="954" height="535" controls class="tm-mb-40">

                    <source src="video/wheat-field.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
                      
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.

                </video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ACF Type [Link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/) in the backend to attach video link like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjQCR.jpg)

```
    <?php 
    
    $link_data = get_field('video_link'); 
    
    if(!empty($link_data))
    { 
    $link = $link_data['url'];  
    
    ?>
    
    <video width="954" height="535" controls class="tm-mb-40">
      
        <source src="<?php echo $link; ?>" type="video/mp4">   
                          
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    
    </video>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think choose file under the file type in ACF and Upload it.
After that use the_field there in your above written code.

```
<video width="954" height="535" controls class="tm-mb-40">
  <?php the_field('video');?>

   </video>
```

Comment: It's is not working using the_field(''). at the front-end video is not showing.